# MySql - AVG() and STD() function , weird results...

Tags: mysql, average

I'm going crasy with the results from MySql regarding standard functions: 
- AVG() the average 
- STD() the standard deviation

Check the following results from my table 'Auction':

```
mysql> SELECT avg(buyout) avg FROM auction where buyout <> 0 and item =72988;
+-------------+
| avg         |
+-------------+
| 234337.3622 |
+-------------+
```

That result looks correct, no issue. 
But when I run std:

```
mysql> SELECT std(buyout) std FROM auction where buyout <> 0 and item =72988;
+-------------+
| std         |
+-------------+
| 574373.6098 |
+-------------+
```

! The SDT is greater than AVG (SDT > AVG), and that's... impossible because my AVG>0.

Where am I wrong here ... ? 
thx in advance !

Comment: Any special reason why you believe that the standard div cannot be greater than the average?

Comment: @mtariq : it's just impossible. SDT is always < than the AVG if the AVG is positive.

Comment: @mtariq: See graph; I m looking for the Green arrow, and the blue one is just not possible because we are dealing with prices here. http://data.imagup.com/12/1164203616.png

Comment: If the distribution is normal (or near normal) then yes your results are surprising. Is the data clean? because u can have stdev > avg (for all positive values) if values lie in two extremes. i would suggest exporting data to csv and using Excel or something to verify the avg and stdev.

Comment: The SD can be greater than the average, there is no mathematical constrain to that: `a = [10, 100, 500, 1000]` - `mean(a) = 400.25` - `sd(a) = 454.31`.

Comment: extract of my data : http://wowauction.co.cc/extract_72988.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mathematical constraint saying that if mean is positive it has to be smaller than the standard deviation.

I read the extract of your data in R

```
data <- read.table("extract_72988.csv", h=1, sep="\t")
```

And confirmed that

```
> mean(data$BUYOUT)
[1] 234337.4
> sd(data$BUYOUT)
[1] 574421.3
```

Further analysis of your data shows that it is far from being normally distributed

Here is an histogram of your data:

[image: histogram of buyout]

And here is the histogram of log-transformed data

[image: histogram of log(buyout)]

And finally a normal Q-Q plot

[image: QQ plot]

Comment: A little cleaning of the data will ensure a good interpretation of the sdt. thank you for the good graph !

Answer (score -1):

Or said differently, we are looking at auction prices. Each price in the database is a positive value. Our mean is not reduced nor centered, and is around 2.35, but the computation of the st.dev returns a higher value than 2.35. If we put this result as a graph, it would mean that the prices move around the mean of a value greater than the mean itself, If we draw this standard deviation "to the left" from our mean, then it would say that there is probability to find a NEGATIVE price -> impossible !

Right ?